# PHP Get Data FOR NEXT PHP

Tags: php

I have PHP code that I don't know if it works so I need help to see if its workable...

one.php

```
$var = 'Name_here';
echo '<input type="text" name="name12" value="'.$var.'", PHP_EO>';
```

two.php

```
include("shop.php");
$sname = $var;
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, UserChanges, PIC) VALUES ('$sname', '$pass', '3', '0')";
```

Would this work? To get the textbox values from another php form Thanks!

Comment: This is way to vague to answer..What is `$pass` and `$sname`? What does your error log show? What does the current page show?

Answer (score 0):

One.php file should have following code

```
 <form action="two.php" method="post">     
    <?Php 
          $var = 'Name_here';
          echo '<input type="text" name="name" value="'.$var.'", PHP_EO>';
          echo '<input type="password" name="pass" value="'.$var.'", PHP_EO>';
    ?>
```

Two.php

```
include("shop.php");
$sname = $var;
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, UserChanges, PIC) VALUES ('". $_REQUEST["name"] ."', '". $_REQUEST["pass"] ."', '3', '0')";

$servername = "localhost"; 
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$conn->query($sql);
```

Check this code.